# Shiny App that include HTML files doesnt render images when is running in command

Tags: html, r, shiny, batch-processing

Why does running a shiny app in r studio show all the images that are added by html but not when running it in the batch?

For example, I have this simple app that calls an html file that contains 2 images, in r studio the app looks perfectly but when in command it doesn't work.

It doesn't show any kind of error or warning just like it doesn't recognize the image.

[image: Batch Output]

How can it be corrected?

app.R

```
library(shiny)

ui <- tagList(
  includeHTML("www/htmlFile.html")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

htmlFile.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>page1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <h3>Hello world!!</h3>
    <img src="img1.jpg"/>
    <img src="img2.jpg"/>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

So I run the shiny app from the command line:

```
R.exe CMD BATCH app.R
```

Comment: what do you mean by " running it in the batch"?

Comment: I mean running the script using -- R.exe CMD BATCH script. R in the command. (I do not know if it is the correct term, excuse me for ignorance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it by running another script that runs the app.R

run.R

```
shiny :: runApp ('app.R')
```

In command:

```
"R.exe" CMD BATCH "run.R"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try `renderImage`. Here's an example:

```
# download some images and save them in the project directory
download.file("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/R_logo.svg/1200px-R_logo.svg.png", destfile = "r.png")
download.file("https://pngset.com/images/r-logo-r-programming-language-logo-text-building-alphabet-dryer-transparent-png-2749164.png", destfile = "r2.png")

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  withTags(
    head(meta(`http-equiv` = "content-type", content = "text/html; charset=utf-8", title("page1")))
  ),
  h3("Hello World!!"),
  imageOutput("img1"),
  imageOutput("img2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$img1 <- renderImage({
    list(
      src = "r.png",
      width = 250,
      hight = 250
    )
  }, deleteFile = TRUE)

  output$img2 <- renderImage({
    list(
      src = "r2.png",
      width = 250,
      hight = 250
    )
  }, deleteFile = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, it is not the solution I was looking for, I need to take the html file as it contains a specific format, it is not just the images.

Comment: The images are located inside the www folder? Another alternative is to host  the images in some cloud service and retrieve them from the internet. <img> tag is not very friendly to local files, at least in shiny.

Comment: Yeah, thanks! i posted my solution below